PDF link not being encoded correctly on one machine but works fine on others
I have come across a pretty unusual issue with an encrypted .pdf one of our users received from their bank.
The encrypted PDF contains a link which on this user's host does not work ( browser loads and the website returns an invalid link error ) . We tested 3 different pdf viewers to no avail.
The same pdf/link work absolutely fine on my own host and a few others i tested it on.
It seems that for the user who is having the issues the URL is not being encoded/decoded correctly ( unsure which terminology to use because i dont know where the issue is occuring ) .
Here is the reason i think there is an issue around encoding/decoding:
Link on users machine ( where it does not work )
www.website.com/blabla/Recipient=SystemMailbox{052a7255-43d1-438f-9edb-4b71771b88aa}@

Link on mine and other hosts where it does work
www.website.com/blabla/Recipient=SystemMailbox%7b052a7255-43d1-438f-9edb-4b71771b88aa%7d%40

Notice how on my host the URL has the special characters encoded correctly but this is not occuring on the users machine.
I have no idea why this would be happening or how to troubleshoot.
Anyone have any ideas?

so you think the issue is with the browser interpreting the url ?
